# What is the difference between app::make and use

Tags: php, laravel

Given I want to initialize a class.

I can do

```
$testClass = App::make('TestClass')   //of course given its already binded on container
```

and

```
$testClass = new TestClass;
```

What is the difference, does `App::make()` when its called resolves the container all the time or ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `App::make` resolves the class using [Laravel container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container) every time. Using the containter is a great idea since you can create an advanced binding, bind a class to an interface, bind a class as a singleton etc.

`new Class` syntax will create a new instance of the Class.

Comment: so all the time I call app::make it will resolve all the classes into ioc container ? Even though I specify only one class

Comment: @PrStandup it's always better to use the container.

Comment: One other good reason for using the container is to be able to mock the object when writing tests

Answer (score 2):

`App:make()` resolves all class constructor dependencies from application container or uses autowiring if dependency is not registered in container.